# Changing a CoreData entity hierarchy

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, entity, hierarchy

I have a CoreData model that looks like this:

- Abstract Entity

  - Entity 1
  - Entity 2

    - Entity 3

"Abstract Entity" is the top entity in the hierarchy.  "Entity 1" and "Entity 2" are peer sub entities of "Abstract Entity".  "Entity 3" is a sub entity of "Entity 2".

The app is live in the App Store, so any amendments to the model must retain all existing data.  Unfortunately, I now need to re-arrange the model hierarchy to look like this:

- Abstract Entity

  - Entity 2

    - Entity 3

      - Entity 1

Is there any way of achieving this that doesn't involve creating a new "Entity 4" entity and writing a function that will convert all "Entity 1" data into "Entity 4" format?  I'd rather not end up with a crufty hierarchy like this:

- Abstract Entity

  - Entity 1
  - Entity 2

    - Entity 3

      - Entity 4

The only way I've come up with of avoiding the above is to copy all of the properties I need from entities 2 and 3 into 1 and just ignore the hierarchy problem entirely, which is a bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you read up on and create a custom [mapping model](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH5-SW1).